# How to create a container widget with variable height which cannot be more than specified?

Tags: flutter, containers

I have Column widget with two widgets as childred. First is a TextField, second is a Container. I need to limit the Container's width with device screen width (minus some Padding). If there is enough space in vertical axis, Container's height must be equal to its width (i.e. Container is square). If there is no enough space in height I need to set Container's height to some value which will avoid overflow. I tried to place Container into Expanded widget but it expands to available height on different devices. I need to limit Container by height of available vertical spance. Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your widget should have 0 <= height <= width and width should always fill your screen. You can do it like this:

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return ConstrainedBox(
       constraints: BoxConstraints(
         maxHeight: 0,
         maxHeight: constraints.maxWidth,
         minWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
         maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
       ),
       child: [CONTENT_HERE]
    );
  }
)
```

Comment: Igor, thank you for a quick answer. But I wrote that I have a Column widget with 2 children. And I need to expand only seconds (Container) widget.